# Ruby equivalent of hash.key access like in Javascript?

Tags: ruby, hash

In Javascript properties can be accessed directly with barewords:

```
var evil = {"knievel":"evel","daredevil":"fearless"}
evil["knievel"] // "evel"
evil.knievel    // "evel"
```

Is there anything similar in Ruby without having to do `evil["knievel"]`?

Comment: Really, why does this have a -1? (I'm out of votes or I'd fix the situation.)

Comment: Ruby does all sorts of wonderful things may be there was a short cut of some sort where keys could be accessed as methods and return values.

Answer (score 2):

```
require "ostruct"

evil = OpenStruct.new(:knievel => "evel",:daredevil => "fearless")
puts evil.knievel
```